# Abrir un archivo en uso por otro programa

Tags: powershell

Estoy intentando acceder, mediante un código de powershell insertado en un bat, a un archivo de log creado por otro programa pero me da el siguiente error:

*Excepci¢n al llamar a "OpenRead" con los argumentos "1": "El proceso no puede 
obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Users\g\Documents\BAT\GrabI.log' porque est  
siendo utilizado en otro proceso.*

El código de powershell utilizado es el siguiente:

```
@PowerShell  ^
    $N = 200; ^
    $fpath = 'Grab%1.log';  ^
    $fs = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($fpath);  ^
    $fs.Seek(-$N, 'End') ^| Out-Null;  ^
    $mystr = '';  ^
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $N; $i++)  ^
    {  ^
        $mystr = ($mystr) + ([char[]]($fs.ReadByte()));  ^
    }  ^
    Write-Host $mystr > logtmp%1.log
%End PowerShell%
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer el Open que me permita acceder al archivo en modo lectura aunque esté en uso?

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en esta página no he tenido mucha "audiencia", en la matriz sí que ha habido personas que han intentado echarme una mano. Pero al final he encontrado la solución a mis necesidades recurriendo a la función Get-Content en lugar de intentar abrir y tratar el archivo de log. Este es el código que me ha funcionado:

```
@PowerShell  ^
    $N = 200; ^
    $mystr = Get-Content 'Grab%1.log' ^| Select-Object -last 1;  ^
    Write-Host $mystr.substring($mystr.length-$N,$N) > logtmp%1.log
%End PowerShell%
```